# How is Adventurer Bell's limit break obtained?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

After reaching level 60, how can the bond items be obtained so I can limit break adventurer Bell?

Answer (score 1):

Adventurer Bell's bonds are obtained by completing missions on hard difficulty. You get the first one from mission 1-1.

[image: Bond Rewards]